# Selecting a specific path in svg created by Raphael.js to delete it

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, this

I have a svg div which is dynamically created using Raphael.sketchpad.js as:

```
<svg height="1094.484" version="1.1" width="773.75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg_0" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; z-index: 3; pointer-events: none;">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;"></desc>
    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); -webkit-user-select: text;"></defs>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M256.25,857L258.25,857L264.25" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; -webkit-user-select: text;"></path>
    <path fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M400.25,178L399.25,179L395.25,185L395.25" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-linecap: round; stroke-linejoin: round; -webkit-user-select: text;"></path>
</svg>
```

The paths are dynamically generated when drawn on the html page.

Now, I want to be able select any specific path in SVG, on which when I right-click should give me options to delete or change stroke colour of that path.
I cannot attach an id to any path.

How will I be able to select a particular path?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to add a handler/s, so 'this' would refer to the element clicked on.

Comment: Could you please let me know, how I can add handlers and work with 'this' ?

Comment: Its not clear if you mean you just have an svg, as above, or if you are integrating sketchpad.js and this is just an example. My best guess would be to use Raphael to attach a click handler onto the SVG. But you would probably need to put up the working code on a jsfiddle.